# Getting Count on 2 columns on SQL

Tags: sql, count

I am trying to get a count on approved orders in a separate column.
Initial Table looks like this,

| User name | Status | Count |
| --- | --- | --- |
| User 1 | Approved | 1 |
|  | Rejected | 2 |
| User 2 | Approved | 5 |
| User 3 | Approved | 1 |
| User 4 | Approved | 2 |
|  | Rejected | 5 |

But I want to get another column as a Approved Count,

| User name | Status | Count | Approved Count |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| User 1 | Approved | 1 | 1 |
|  | Rejected | 2 |  |
| User 2 | Approved | 5 | 5 |
| User 3 | Approved | 1 | 1 |
| User 4 | Approved | 2 | 2 |
|  | Rejected | 5 |  |

What is the best way of doing this?

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to do something like this:

```
Select Count(User_Id) FROM table WHERE Status = 'Approved'
```

You could also try adding `GROUP BY User_Id` at the end

Answer (score 0):

You could try something using a [case](https://mode.com/sql-tutorial/sql-case/) statement.

```
SELECT 
    Username, 
    Status, 
    Count,
    CASE 
        WHEN Status = 'Approved' 
            THEN Count
            ELSE ''
    END AS approved_count
FROM 
    table1
```

[db fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/5W5R4mkRTSZ9w9YLYSwfvk/0)

Answer (score 0):

Try this one. I used same column names as you mentioned, but not recommended

Your impotent part is this one:

```
case when Status = 'Approved' then count else 0 end
```

> Example

```
select *, case when Status = 'Approved' then count else 0 end   Approved_count from  table_X
where row_num = 1;
```

> Full sample code

```
select *, case when Status = 'Approved' then count else 0 end   Approved_count from (
select  ROW_NUMBER() OVER (partition by user_name, Status ORDER BY user_name) row_num, 
user_name, Status, count(Status) over (partition by user_name, Status) count  
from [Count_test] )
A where row_num = 1;
```